# How to discount additional recurring payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to charge $47/month for the first month. Then only $37 for every additional month. Essentially, I want to discount the recurring payments if they stay with me.

How can I do this in PayPal buttons?

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="your-email-address@yourdomain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Subscription description here">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="a1" value="47.00"> <!-- Set this to the price you want to charge them upfront -->
    <input type="hidden" name="p1" value="1"> <!-- Set the length of the trial to 1 interval (t1 will define the interval) -->
    <input type="hidden" name="t1" value="M"> <!-- Set the interval to months -- trial is now one month in length -->
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="37.00"> <!-- Amount to charge each month -->
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M"> <!-- Payments are one month apart -->
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- Payments don't automatically stop -->
    <input type="image" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif">
</form>
```

Comment: So your solution is to create a trial that is mandatory and higher priced than the product?

Comment: Yep.  Not what you normally think of for a trial period, but it's a perfectly valid use case.

Comment: It will work perfectly, as long as PayPal doesn't say the word "trial." As the product is really $47/month, but it's only $37/month if you stick around.

Comment: PayPal doesn't use the word "trial".  Here's how it shows up: [link](http://i63.tinypic.com/b657k6.jpg)